# Android studio 2.0 SDK Validation warning about ANDROID_SDK_HOME?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-sdk-tools

I encountered this warning when using Android Studio 2.0. What does this mean?

> SDK Validation
>
> ANDROID_SDK_HOME is set to the root of your SDK: C:\Users\Sujin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk This is the path of the preference folder expected by the Android tools. It should NOT be set to the same as the root of your SDK. Please set it to a different folder or do not set it at all. If this is not set we default to: C:\Users\Sujin

Answer (score 2):

You should move out the SDK directory to a distinct directory then the Android Studio folder. This has changed in Android Studio 1.3 or 1.4 the reason is that before the patch mechanism got trouble if there where *unexpected* changes and you where unable to update Android Studio.

When you moved that directory outside keep in mind to update the path in your settings (*`File > Preferences`*) and there in *`Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK`*.

Answer (score -2):

If you run with the x64 Ubuntu you may have to install these things

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
```

It maybe help you.