# Flutter: Error with env paths ANDROID_SDK_HOME

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I tried to run the project on an android emulator and get the following error. I have mac os. Thank you all in advance for your help in solving this issue.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio 3.1.4 : ANDROID\_SDK\_HOME is set to the root of your SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52125866/android-studio-3-1-4-android-sdk-home-is-set-to-the-root-of-your-sdk)